# What is the pronunciation of "Will you" in fast/connected speech?

Tags: pronunciation, future-tense, connected-speech

I usually pronounce "will you" as "/wɪ/ + /lju:/", but seems that people have some troubles understanding me (at least here in the UK). Is my pronunciation wrong? That's the way we usually make the linking sound between a consonant and a vowel. If so, what should be the proper pronunciation? Should this be as "/wɪl/ + /lju:/" (that's how google translator pronounces it, apparently)? Or there's no way to connect these words and I should say "/wɪl/ + /ju:/" ?

Comment: Based only on what you wrote here I don't see the problem. It'd be easier to nudge you in the right direction if you upload the recording of yourself saying 'will you'.

Comment: When we're speaking English, we don't put breaks in between words. So /wɪ/ + /lju:/, /wɪl/ + /lju:/, /wɪl/ + /ju:/ all sound the same. You must be doing something to put breaks between words, and that's what's confusing people.

Answer (score 1):

Before being able to respond, I would need to know whether or not you are a native English speaker and which region or country you come from. There are several regional variants in English which can to some extent be mutually unintelligible; for example, I am Scottish, from Glasgow, and once knew a man from the Newcastle area whose Geordie accent I found very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the pronunciation of “Will you” in fast/connected speech?

In standard American English, without a regional accent, it usually sounds like the regular word "will" (not wl, wll, wull, or well) attached to the regular word "you", so "willyou".  I don't believe any sounds are dropped or omitted.  Arguably, the ll sound is equally connected to both the first part and the second part of the word "willyou".

Comment: The OP is using the capital letter I to represent the “short i” sound, as in the word “will”. It’s a transcription system called SAMPA

Answer (score 0):

The vowel sounds are heavily dependent on dialect, though the 'i' in *will* is usually a short one. The vowel in *you* might be a schwa, a short 'a', or a long 'u' or 'oo' sound.

What makes it fast/connected is what happens to the 'l' and consonant 'y' sounds. In my experience, it ends up like the '*lli*' in *mi**lli**on*, which is, I believe, much like the *ll* that used to be considered a separate letter in Spanish - but only in Spanish-Spanish (e.g. Castilian), not Latin American Spanish.